# Why does my script give me a message can't find element in my if statement?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have written a script for a calendar.  The calendar is fairly simple looking box pop up, you have a header showing the month, obviously all the days and dates in the box.  On the top left corner, there is an arrow to go back to previous month.  The calendar will always by default show the current month i.e. at this point in time its November, so it shows all the days and dates in a grid format like any other general calendar out there.  The intention of my script is to go to May so my code is the following:

```
string currentMthText = reportRep.currentMthHeader.Text;

if (reportRep.currentMthHeader.Displayed)
{                   
    while (1==1)
    {                  
        reportRep.datePreviousBtn.Click();
        if (reportRep.MayMthHeader.Displayed)
        {
            reportRep.mon6MayPicker("mon", "6").Click();
        }
        break;                    
    }        
}
```

But it hangs for a good 60 secs and gives me the error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='react-datepicker__current-month'][text()='May 2019']"}

Of course there is no element with May 2019, that's why I put a previous click button in my code until it reaches the header month May 2019, so why doesn't it ignore the month and go round the loop again pressing the previous button until it meets the if condition statement and I can choose the day and date?

Comment: How does `currentMthText` change inside the `while` loop?

Comment: `currentMthText` is never changed inside the loop. So it will always have the value you assigned it before the loop and the loop repeats forever.

Comment: Ah @RonBeyer you have a point so for the xpath I need a contains function, can you recommend me one?

Comment: @Butler there is only one "contains" function in XPath...

Comment: Its not the while loop, its the if statement it doesn't like

Comment: Here is my locator IWebdriver MayMthHeader = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='react-datepicker__header']//div[text()[contains(.,'May 2019')]]"));

Comment: What to do now because the Display function doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting error message `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException` is because the element `reportRep.MayMthHeader` which you are trying to find is not present in the DOM as current month is November and not May and IWebElement.Display only works if element is present in the DOM.

Note : IWebElement.Display only tells if the element is displayed or not, it does not say if element is present in the DOM. In order for IWebElement.Display to work you must have element present in the DOM.

I would suggest not to find element based on the Text it contains but try to find the header element and get the text of the element and then verify whether it contains 'May 2019' or not(as this is what you want to verify).

As your intention is to go to May, you can try something like this :

```
string currentMthText = reportRep.currentMthHeader.Text;
int count = 15;
if (reportRep.currentMthHeader.Displayed)
{                   
    while (count!=0)
    {                  
        if (reportRep.currentMthHeader.Text=="May 2019")
        {
            reportRep.mon6MayPicker("mon", "6").Click();
            break;  
        }
        else 
        {
            reportRep.datePreviousBtn.Click();
        }
        count--;                 
    }        
}
```

Also please have some way of existing the loop, because if driver couldn't find text it will go in an infinite loop.